# CSS Grid, max-heigh 100% не работает

Tags: html, css, grid

CSS

```
.profile_images {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.347fr repeat(3, 0.217fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 254px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 21px 146.2px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.profile_images img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Вот, что выходит: http://prntscr.com/quto98
Как сделать так: http://prntscr.com/qutolh

И, вопрос второй:
Как изменить grid-template-columns во второй строке (grid-template-rows) на такой формат: 0.217fr 0.347fr 0.217fr 0.217fr
А третью строку: 0.217fr 0.217fr 0.217fr 0.347 fr?

Comment: вы же сами написали repeat(3,  0.217fr) напишите 4

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyPEwKa - не max-width max-height а width и height

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid: 100px / repeat(4, 1fr);
}

div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```